# Shift cipher without knowing the key

Tags: arrays, c, string, for-loop, if-statement

I am writing a program to find the solution of a shift cipher without knowing the key.The code is around the length of 400 words without any signs like (, . ! :) and all in capital letters. There are two part in my program, the first one is to output all 25 possible solutions and separately store inside an array. The first part have no errors and  can work just fine. The second part is to find in the 25 possible solution with the most character "E" "A" "R" "I" "O", than print the 5 possible solution. Thats where the problem occurred, if i enter something like "VDDDDDDDDC" it will start printing the wrong code.
Here is my program.
(The switch choice is for further function which i will work on it later, the one which have errors is the first one.)
(Also if there are better ways to do it beside spamming if please let me know :D)
(I am pretty new at c so explain would be really helpful):D

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()  
{  
char code[400];char after[400];char store[25][400]; // variable initialization  
//store form 1 not 0
int f,x,choice,z,temp,y,q,e=0,a=0,r=0,i=0,o=0;
int ce=0,ca=0,cr=0,ci=0,co=0;
int se=0,sa=0,sr=0,si=0,so=0;

printf("                     Welcome\n");
printf("Enter your code here:\n");
scanf("%[^'\n']s",code); 
printf("Press 1 to Decrypt\nPress 2 to encrypt\nPress 3 to Exit\nEnter your choice here: ");
scanf("%d",&choice);
printf(" ");
  
 //case 1 is decryption 
switch(choice){  
case 1:
for(x=1;x<=25;x++){//loop to shift the character
for(f=0;(f<=400 && code[f]!=0);f++)  // for loop to print out all the possible solutions  
{  //thie two loop with ouput all 25 result and store in an array,this part have no problems and it can print all 25 result. (as far as i test) 
  e=0,a=0,r=0,i=0,o=0;
   if(code[f]==32){//32 means space in ascii code
     store[x][f]=32;
     continue;//if there is a space it will continue
   }
   if(code[f]>=65 && code[f]<=90){
       if(code[f]+x>90){
       store[x][f]=((code[f]+x)-90)+64;
       continue;
     }
    }
    if(code[f]+x>122 && code[f]>96){
     after[f]=((code[f]+x)-122)+96;
    }
    else{
    store[x][f]=code[f]+x;
    }
}
store[x][f] = '\0'; 
printf("After decrypting:%s\n", store[x]);  
printf("%s\n",code);
}

for(x=1;x<=25;x++){//this is where i have problems
  for(f=0;(f<=400 && code[f]!=0);f++){  // for loop to start finding the words, i am trying to find the possible solution which have the most E A R I O
  if(store[x][f]=='E'){
    e++;
  }
  if(store[x][f]=='A'){
    a++;
  }
  if(store[x][f]=='R'){
    r++;
  }
  if(store[x][f]=='I'){
    i++;
  }
  if(store[x][f]=='O'){
    o++;
  }
}
if(se<e){//this part is to look for the key of the code
  se=e;
  ce=x;
}
if(sa<a){
  sa=a;
  ca=x;
}
if(sr<r){
  sr=r;
  cr=x;
}
if(si<i){
  si=i;
  ci=x;
}
if(so<o){
  so=o;
  co=x;
}
}
printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n",ce,ca,cr,ci,co);
printf("The program thinks the possible solution are:\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",store[ce],store[ca],store[cr],store[ci],store[co]);
break;

case 2:
  
break;

case 3:
printf("GOODBYE");
break;

default:
printf("Errors");
return 0; 
}

}
```

Comment: Taking the time to format your code properly may help to reveal problems.  Start with that.  And please be more specific about _where_ in the code you are encountering your issues.  (Comments in code can be used to point out where they are.)  Have you stepped though in debug mode?

Comment: Also, comments out to the right of code, such as `for(f=0;(f<=400 && code[f]!=0);f++)  // for loop` make code very hard to read.  Nevermind the fact that a comment such as `// for loop` is worse than useless - it just repeats what the code **obviously** is.  Until the code has to be changed to something like a `while` loop, in which case the comment will no longer match the code, or someone had to spend extra error to fix the comment too.

Comment: My bad, i am not really used to asking question in website like dis :( ,i had change most of the comments(tbh i don't really know what to write so if  there is any problems please let me know). Also is it really important to change the for loop into while loop but doing everything same as the for loop? Thanks for the suggestions :D

Comment: regarding:  `scanf("%[^'\n']s",code);`  the input conversion specifier: `% [...]` is complete.  I.E. there is no trailing `s`.  Appending a `s`